# Winforms: How to dispatch properly collection changes when bound to UI Controls?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, collections

I'm facing some issues when I'm trying to deal with `IBindingList` inherited collections that are modified by a non-UI `Thread` and are at the same time bound to the `DataSource` Property of some Winforms Controls (e.g. an old fashion `DataGridView`).

My point is that `Invoke / Begin` are not suitable in my solution, cause the collections are not supposed to be really aware of the controls they are bound to.

Is there any other elegant solution than passing the UI `Dispatcher` or the appropriate `SynchronizationContext` reference to the collection which is going to be modified later on?

I was thinking about how one can detect whether that the current `Thread` is the UI accessing to the collection? If could know that, 
therefore I could select *to dispatch or not* the collection modifications to the UI `Thread`. This solution still does not prevent to pass the reference of the UI `SynchronizationContext` or `Dispatcher`, though.

It would be nice to have real static properties which could give access, instead we have `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` and `WinformsSynchronizationContext` that actually cannot be accessed from another thread... don't really get the point of the design if we still need to pass the reference from the UI `Thread` then. But I guess there is some reasons behind the scenes.

I may misunderstood and twist the definitions of some terms, so feel free to correct me if that's the case. I do not want to pretend that I'm expert or whatsoever.

The fact that delegating systematically everything to the UI seems a bit too much and might somehow overload the message pump cause in this scenario it would be better to create the collection right beforehand within the UI scope but then it would loose the interest of delegating the modifications among several threads.

I know that `IBindingList` is going to reflect through `ListChanged` (which is subscribed via the Control bound to a `IBindingList` inherited collection) the collection changes. 
Basically those changes are going to be triggered by the non-UI `Thread` and that basically the very bottom line. Although, I'm bit frustrated by the lack of elegant solutions.

By the way, I am not willing to use the async/await and neither some special events of the BackgroundWorker that automatically Marhsall to the UI Thread when they are triggered. Maybe I should have a look at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Please find below the results of my investigations about the UI Marshalling:

```
public static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(params String[] arguments)
    {
        var bindingList = new BindingList<Record>();

        Action<Object> action = (argument) =>
        {
            var synchronizationContext = argument as SynchronizationContext;
            var dispatcher = argument as Dispatcher;

            if ((synchronizationContext == null) && (dispatcher == null))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(@"argument");
            }
            else
            {
                var random = new Random();

                while (true)
                {
                    Action<Object> sendOrPostCallbackAction = (state) =>
                    {
                        var record = new Record();
                        bindingList.Add(record);
                    };

                    var sendOrPostCallback = new SendOrPostCallback(sendOrPostCallbackAction);

                    // WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current.Send(sendOrPostCallback, new Object());
                    // *** NullReferenceException
                    // *** Object reference not set to an instance of an object...
                    // *** Thought this could be found not matter where.
                    // *** Cause the winforms application is already started at that point in the code.

                    // Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(sendOrPostCallback, (Object)null);
                    // *** InvalidOperationException
                    // *** Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

                    if (dispatcher != null)
                    {
                        // Only Works if the synchronizationContext is the one used by the UI Thread...
                        dispatcher.Invoke(sendOrPostCallback, (Object)null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Only Works if the synchronizationContext is the one used by the UI Thread...
                        synchronizationContext.Send(sendOrPostCallback, (Object)null);
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }
        };

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var mainForm = new MainForm
        {
            DataGridView = { DataSource = bindingList },
        };

        mainForm.ButtonPassSynchronizationContext.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            mainForm.ButtonPassSynchronizationContext.Enabled = false;
            mainForm.ButtonPassDispatcher.Enabled = false;
            // Of course here the synchronization context is the one used by the UI Thread...
            // WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current should be equal here.
            var areTheSameSyncrhonizationContexts = SynchronizationContext.Current == WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current;
            Debug.WriteLineIf(areTheSameSyncrhonizationContexts, @"The sychronization contexts are the same.");
            Task.Factory.StartNew(action, SynchronizationContext.Current);
        };

        mainForm.ButtonPassDispatcher.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            mainForm.ButtonPassSynchronizationContext.Enabled = false;
            mainForm.ButtonPassDispatcher.Enabled = false;
            // The dispatcher is indeed not null, since it is the one used by the UI Thread...
            // Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher should be not null here.
            var isDispatcherNotNull = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher != null;
            Debug.WriteLineIf(isDispatcherNotNull, @"The Current Dispatcher is not null.");
            Task.Factory.StartNew(action, Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);
        };

        Application.Run(mainForm);
    }

    public class Record
    {
        public Record()
        {
            var random = new Random();
            this._dummyProperty = random.Next(0, 100);
        }

        private readonly Int32 _dummyProperty;
        public Int32 DummyProperty
        {
            get { return this._dummyProperty; }
        }
    }

    public class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Button ButtonPassSynchronizationContext { get; private set; }
        public Button ButtonPassDispatcher { get; private set; }

        public DataGridView DataGridView { get; private set; }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.Text = @"Main Form";

            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

            this.DataGridView = new DataGridView
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                AllowUserToAddRows = false,
                AllowUserToDeleteRows = false,
                DefaultCellStyle = { Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter },
                AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle = { BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow },
            };


            this.ButtonPassSynchronizationContext = new Button()
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Bottom,
                Text = @"Pass SynchronizationContext",
            };

            this.ButtonPassDispatcher = new Button()
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Bottom,
                Text = @"Pass Dispatcher",
            };

            this.Controls.Add(this.DataGridView);
            this.Controls.Add(this.ButtonPassSynchronizationContext);
            this.Controls.Add(this.ButtonPassDispatcher);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/64936/Multithreaded-ObservableImmutableCollection

Comment: @mDC: Already had a look at it, but I have to admit, quite a long time ago ( a year or 6 months ago), but seems so far that I'm not (only?) using mutable collections.
Anyway thanks for pointing out that article I'm going to go through it once again. I might have missed a couple of points last time.

Comment: You're right, I prefer using collections instead of lists :) In that context: months ago I read an article about a thread-safe ObservableCollection. I can't find it, though. The implementation did something similar to what you proposed. HTH